# Where can I write a script that communicates with a Telegram Bot?

Tags: scripting, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using a bot on Telegram (which I didn't create), and I communicate with it by sending commands like "/start" and "/help"

I need to write a script that does that communication for me automatically, but I don't know where to start...

I'm using "Telegram Desktop" on my Windows 10 device, so I tried to write a batch file, but I couldn't make it control my Telegram account, and I found out about a software called "Telegram-CLI" which I can use to control my account from the terminal but it only works on Linux. 
I also tried to make a bot on Telegram, but this method won't work because I need to be communicating with the original bot from my account (not from another bot).

What other tools can be used to achieve that?

Comment: You can use browser automation with whatsapp web, like Selenium or iMacros, or even write a chrome extension.

Comment: Selenium looks promising, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many more clients except `telegram-cli` like `MadelineProto` which introduced [here](https://telegram.org/apps) or [tdlib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) official telegram library.
in addition i personally user [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/) to create my scripts. [TLsharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) and [telegram-mtproto](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto) are other choices.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to MadelineProto. I've been using it since, and very pleased with that experience. Today, I got the reputaion needed for an upvote, and wanted to use a late thank you!